# Upload file to Sharepoint document library together with all properties

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-api

Is there any way upload file to Sharepoint document library together with all properties (in one REST call) ? I found recently if I uploaded a file and the it's properties (doesn't matter what properties), for Sharepoint it's a new version of the file and it's consumes storage as previous version, so for example I upload large file (4gb) and then it's some custom properties , now this files will consume 8gb storage, regardless if file itself was changed or not.
In Sharepoint SOAP it possible, but in REST seems that not.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do them separately and it doesn't actually create a copy of the file. SharePoint stores the deltas and in your case, there wouldn't be a change in the document.  When you look at the version history, it can be misleading b/c you will see version 1.0 is 4GB and version 2.0 is 4GB which would make you think that you are consuming 8GB but that is not the case.  If you were add a 3rd version that was 5GB, you wouldn't have 13GB used.  Instead, the database will only store 5GB of data and SharePoint essentially pieces together the file from the database.

Comment: Thanks, now it clear, but their UI is confusing, and in my case I need to prove to customer that I didn't eat his storage twice, as he sees it twice.